# Build error MakePRI : error 0x8007007e

Tags: c#, msbuild, windows-phone-8.1

I have following problem during build Blank App for Windows Phone 8.1 Application:

```
1>MakePRI : error 0x8007007e: Unspecified error occurred.
1>  The command exited with code -2147024770. (TaskId:114)
```

I've read this [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721621/windows-8-1-store-app-makepri-build-error) and I've found

```
1>Using "GenerateProjectPriFile" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.dll".
1>Task "GenerateProjectPriFile" (TaskId:114)
1>  Task Parameter:MakePriExeFullPath=C:\Program Files(x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\\bin\x86\MakePri.exe (TaskId:114)
1>  Task Parameter:MakePriExtensionPath=C:\Program Files(x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\bin\x86\MrmEnvironmentExtDl.dll (TaskId:114)
1>  Task Parameter:PriConfigXmlPath=obj\x86\Debug\priconfig.xml (TaskId:114)
1>  Task Parameter:
1>      IndexFilesForQualifiersCollection=
1>          obj\x86\Debug\layout.resfiles
1>          obj\x86\Debug\resources.resfiles (TaskId:114)
1>  Task Parameter:ProjectPriIndexName=08d39f94-f55b-4d4f-94a9-91c2f594be57(TaskId:114)
1>  Task Parameter:InsertReverseMap=False(TaskId:114)
1>  Task Parameter:ProjectDirectory=E:\Projects\Samples\ScrollViewerSampleApp\ (TaskId:114)
1>  Task Parameter:OutputFileName=E:\Projects\Samples\ScrollViewerSampleApp\bin\x86\Debug\resources.pri (TaskId:114)
1>  Task Parameter:QualifiersPath=obj\x86\Debug\qualifiers.txt (TaskId:114)
1>  Task Parameter:IntermediateExtension=.intermediate(TaskId:114)
1>  Task Parameter:AppxBundleAutoResourcePackageQualifiers=Language|Scale|DXFeatureLevel(TaskId:114)
1>  Task Parameter:MultipleQualifiersPerDimensionFoundPath=obj\x86\Debug\MultipleQualifiersPerDimensionFound.txt (TaskId:114)
1>  C:\Program Files(x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\\bin\x86\MakePri.exe New -ProjectRoot E:\Projects\Samples\ScrollViewerSampleApp\ -ConfigXml obj\x86\Debug\priconfig.xml -OutputFile E:\Projects\Samples\ScrollViewerSampleApp\bin\x86\Debug\resources.pri -ExtensionDll "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\bin\x86\MrmEnvironmentExtDl.dll" -IndexName 08d39f94-f55b-4d4f-94a9-91c2f594be57 -Verbose -Overwrite(TaskId:114)
1>  Option Verbose specified(TaskId:114)
1>  Option Overwrite specified(TaskId:114)
1>MakePRI : error 0x8007007e: Unspecified error occurred.
1>  The command exited with code -2147024770. (TaskId:114)
```

As I can see VS doesn't use something wrong. At last time (it was 2 weeks ago) I repaired VS with WP8.1 SDK. But it had happened again and I want to know what the reason for this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not that unspecified, the error code indicates that makepri.exe cannot find a DLL it needs to get its job done.  You'll need to get your machine fixed.

Comment: It worked yesterday, It worked 2 hours ago but now I can't build wp81 app. I didn't anything extraordinary

Comment: Well, doesn't sound like it worked 2 weeks ago.  Reboot, disable anti-malware, replace hard disk, roughly in order.

Comment: during this time I had updated OS version. that's all. BUT it works 2 hours ago. I'd installed `CISCO VPN Client`. Could it breaks building?

Comment: Hi @AndriiKrupka I have the same issue with an exported Unity project for windows phone 8.1. Do you resolve this ?

Comment: @ejanowski I repaired Visual Studio and this helped me